# Char array gives the whole array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am facing a problem understanding the behaviour of arrays....

For the code below-

```
int iarray[]={1,2,3,4};
cout<<iarray;
cout<<iarray[i];
```

i understand that iarray will give the address of the first element of the array whereas iarray[i] will give the ith element.

Whereas,for the following code

```
char carray[4]={'m','a','x'};
cout<<carray;
cout<<carray[i];
```

why is the output of the first statement 'max',i was expecting the address of the first element as in the case of int array.Also,how will i get the address of the first char array element than.

Thank You!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your char array decays into a pointer-to-char (`char *`), and since this data type has a special significance (namely, it generally represents C strings), operators on standard streams are overloaded so that when they encounter a `char *`, they will treat it as a string and output the contents of the string instead of a pointer.

Use `std::cout << (void *)&carray[0];` instead.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just write it out as `(void*)carray` as `carray` still points to the address of the first element.

Comment: @ZacHowland That's true, I just wanted to be explicit. I don't want to lead anyone into the false assumption that an array is a pointer.

Comment: @H2CO3 i appreciate your help but you wrote that  "operators on standard streams are overloaded so that when they encounter a char *, they will treat it as a string and output the contents of the string instead of a pointer", i wonder that how does the standard stream determines the size of the string or the amount of data it has to display!!!

Comment: @Max It prints everything up to a 0 byte.

Comment: @Max:  It looks for a null-terminator.  If you don't have one, you end up with trouble.

Comment: @ZacHowland - That depends on how you define "trouble"!

Comment: @phonetagger:  Accessing array index out of bounds = undefined behavior kind of "trouble" ...

Comment: Ok! but in the above code if i do not specify the index for carray while declaration(which i can) than the statement 
cout<<carray;
is giving some garbage values following the actual array....Please explain.

Comment: @Max Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: @H2CO3 Sorry for the confusion,I mean to say that if suppose i write char carray[]={'m','a','x'}; and than cout<<carray; Than the output contains the actual array plus some garbage characters i.e. something like max@#ef$!

Comment: @Max No, because in an aggregate initializer (when you initialize an array or a struct using the `{ }` syntax), uninitialized elements are implicitly initialized to zero.

Comment: @H2CO3 I don't think there are any uninitialized elements,since the size is not given carray will be of 4 bytes 3 array characters + 1 null character.Also, i realy am getting this type of result on g++.

Comment: @Max `char carray[4]={'m','a','x'};` - m, a and x are only three characters. The last (fourth) one is implicitly zero. Compiler is irrelevant.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes, you are right since you mentioned the array index=4.Please see my comment above carefully, i did not mentioned the index and it is this case when i get the junk results.

Comment: @Max Then that's because you don't have a trailing `NUL` (0) character. It works like that. You should read a good beginner C book, it seems that you don't have a basic understanding of C strings. I won't be able to teach you the whole topic in comments.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks for your help!!! I too think that i must get back to my beginner book(I am a beginner though).Thanks once again....

Answer (score 0):

Probably because it is treated as a char* (a string).
In C++, char arrays are also used to represent text strings "like this".